# Ubuntu 18.04 "Bluetooth not set up"

Tags: 18.04, bluetooth

I am trying to connect airpods and my other pair of headphones to xps13 Ubuntu 18.04. My laptop can find Bluetooth devices; however, I always get that not set up status. I tried setting it up by clicking on the not set up, but it won't. How do I fix this?

[image: bluetooth]

Comment: Did you figure it out?

Comment: @JPi nope, couldn't get it to work :(

Comment: I made them work, take a look at here: https://askubuntu.com/a/1123633/782482

Answer (score 12):

Installing package *"blueman"* will help you.

First launch the terminal by pressing <kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>alt</kbd> + <kbd>T</kbd>

Then run the command in terminal:

```
sudo service bluetooth start
```

Install *blueman* by typing to terminal:

```
sudo apt-get install blueman bluez-utils bluez bluetooth
```

Now again type to terminal:

```
sudo service bluetooth restart
```

If not installed, install blueman:

```
sudo apt-get install blueman
```

Now launch *Blueman* and then connect your devices from the blueman window by searching followed by pairing.

Comment: Saved the Christmas! You will need to have lots of patience, even delete the pairing and pair again. But it'll work.