# Bluetooth "works" but won't pair with headphones. rtl8723de HP laptop

Tags: drivers, bluetooth, 18.10, rtl8723be

After having gone through the following threads and following the answers:

Wireless was not working: [Realtek Semiconductor RTL8723DE Device d723 issue](https://askubuntu.com/questions/983251/realtek-semiconductor-rtl8723de-device-d723-issue)

Bluetooth was not working: [How to activate bluetooth device for RTL8723DE?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1033968/how-to-activate-bluetooth-device-for-rtl8723de) (I am using cosmic but specified the bionic repo to pull down the module)

My bluetooth adapter searches for and finds headphones, but will not connect to them. The adapter will connect to my phone's bluetooth though, so I'm really confused as to what is causing this. I have tried the suggestion here: [ubuntu 18.04 bluetooth not set up](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1077668/ubuntu-18-04-bluetooth-not-set-up) without any luck. The description of what is happening with my headphones in that post is spot on.

EDIT: I have tried to connect with two different known working headsets.

As I've seen requested in some other posts:

```
user@Slacker:/var/log$ lspci -knn | grep Net -A3; lsusb
02:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. Device [10ec:d723]
    Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company Device [103c:8319]
    Kernel driver in use: rtl8723de
    Kernel modules: rtl8723de
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 005: ID 04f3:250e Elan Microelectronics Corp. 
Bus 001 Device 004: ID 0bda:b009 Realtek Semiconductor Corp. 
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 05c8:03c7 Cheng Uei Precision Industry Co., Ltd (Foxlink) 
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 046d:c52b Logitech, Inc. Unifying Receiver
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
user@Slacker:/var/log$ dmesg | grep -i blue
[    4.735816] Bluetooth: Core ver 2.22
[    4.735830] Bluetooth: HCI device and connection manager initialized
[    4.735834] Bluetooth: HCI socket layer initialized
[    4.735836] Bluetooth: L2CAP socket layer initialized
[    4.735845] Bluetooth: SCO socket layer initialized
[    4.893865] Bluetooth: hci0: rtl: examining hci_ver=08 hci_rev=826c lmp_ver=08 lmp_subver=8873
[    4.893866] Bluetooth: hci0: rtl: assuming no firmware upload needed
[    5.854947] Bluetooth: BNEP (Ethernet Emulation) ver 1.3
[    5.854948] Bluetooth: BNEP filters: protocol multicast
[    5.854951] Bluetooth: BNEP socket layer initialized
[   16.677354] Bluetooth: RFCOMM TTY layer initialized
[   16.677360] Bluetooth: RFCOMM socket layer initialized
[   16.677363] Bluetooth: RFCOMM ver 1.11
```

Please let me know if there is any other information needed to help troubleshoot this.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The bluetooth is working on my system, this is an issue with the signal strength. There is a known issue with the lwfinger driver ([Bluetooth Range Issue](https://github.com/lwfinger/rtlwifi_new/issues/425) that will not be fixed. I am moving on with my life as this is apparently unsolvable.