# Connecting Sony XB900N in Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: 16.04, bluetooth, headphones, sony

I'm not able to connect my Sony XB900N Bluetooth headset in Ubuntu 16.04. I tried using the default Bluetooth manager and `blueman`. Both failed to add the device.

What could be the problem?

Blueman error:
[image: blueman error]

Default bluetooth manager error:
[image: default bluetooth manager error]

Comment: Please edit to include results from terminal for `pactl list short | grep blue`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First, make sure yours are set into pairing mode. Read the headset manual to find how to do so.

To open a terminal, press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>T</kbd>
Now, type `bluetoothctl` in terminal, you should see the available bluetooth devices

```
[NEW] Device a1:b2:c3:d4:55:f6
```

To pair with the headset, type

```
pair 00:12:D0:01:F4:E5
```

Once paired, connect to the headset

```
connect 00:12:D0:01:F4:E5
```

Open `Settings` > `Sound and check sound` options to see if you are using the correct output device(headset).

Comment: From bluetoothctl I have a long list of '[DEL] Device B4:65:1E:22:AF:9F ....' (for example). May I ask how to identify which one is the accidentally 'forgotten' headset? I had to remove at least 3 dozens unknown mac addresses in my bluetooth list, but accidentally removed my headset. The headset name is not coming back ever :(

Answer (score 1):

I made it working somehow. Not sure how. I think the problem was with pairing. I disconnected (unpaired) all other devices including my android phone. Then tried again. It got connected in the first attempt but audio was not coming. After trying multiple times connecting and disconnecting the device using bluetooth manager and powering ON and OFF the headset, It's working well now. But I'm afraid if it'll get connect after I reboot my system. I don't have a systematic plan to get it working. It was just trial and error!!

Comment: Glad that you could solve the problem