# Razer Nari Bluetooth?

Tags: bluetooth, headset

Got these headsets as a gift.  So far, following the documentation, although for Windows, Bluetooth doesn't seem to "detect" the device.  I plug the USB cable in (the one used for charging), and it seems to see the Nari Headsets...

Anyone have any luck getting the Bluetooth to work?

Comment: I have already answered the question here https://askubuntu.com/a/1194503/890892

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Connecting Sony XB900N in Ubuntu 16.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1194464/connecting-sony-xb900n-in-ubuntu-16-04)

Answer (score -1):

the wireless part works with a usb dongle that is stored in the right ear cup. I am currently looking for a way to just connect it to my network card... maybe it works. i mean they botch use 2.4 GHz i don't even know they they are using am or fm, soo that will be interesting.

Answer (score -1):

It doesn't support bluetooth (in the classic sense) at all. Use the dongle you get with it or use the audio cable.