# How to setup bluetooth usb adapter and headphone on bluetooth - Ubuntu 18.04 LTS

Tags: 18.04, bluetooth

I've got a new bluetooth Headphone (WH-XB700) and a new bluetooth usb adapter , but when I turn on my bluetooth it doeesnt find anything. If I *run sudo lsusb |grep Bluetooth* it outputs:

> Bus 001 Device 003: ID 0a12:0001 Cambridge Silicon Radio, Ltd
>   Bluetooth Dongle (HCI mode)

By running *sudo bluetoothctl* it was just saying 'waiting to connect to bluetoothd' so I ran *sudo /etc/init.d/bluetooth restart* and then I was able to run *sudo bluetoothctl*

Trying to connect this is the output:

> [bluetooth]# agent on Agent registered [bluetooth]# default-agent
>   Default agent request successful [bluetooth]# scan on Failed to start
>   discovery: org.bluez.Error.NotReady

I tried running by b*luetoothctl power* on but also didnt work. I i do *rfkill list* everything is unblocked as listed below.

> 1: hci0: Bluetooth    Soft blocked: no    Hard blocked: no

I tried running some commands to gather some intel as to what the problem was but I wasnt able to solve it

```
 dmesg | grep blue
```

> [ 2037.431830] bluetoothd[908]: segfault at 0 ip 00005655555bc6b6 sp 00007ffbffffb830 error 4 in bluetoothd[565555553000+f3000]

```
bluetoothd
```

> D-Bus setup failed: Connection ":1.212" is not allowed to own the service "org.bluez" due to security policies in the configuration file

Comment: Does this answer solve your problem? https://askubuntu.com/a/1194503/890892

Comment: No, if i try to pair or anything in bluetoothctl i get the error pair: org.bluez.Error.AuthenticationFailed or NotReady. I cant set power on on bluetoothctl