# Bluetooth not working on HP Spectre - Ubuntu 19.10

Tags: drivers, bluetooth

My bluetooth is not working on my HP Spectre using Ubuntu 19.10.

I have searched and searched and tried various terminal commands: rfkill, block/unblock, blue, blueman, bluez, /etc/init.d/bluetooth start...

I think it might be to do with "01:00.0 Unassigned class [ff00]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTS525A" but that's just a hunch.

Please see terminal outputs. Very grateful for assistance???

```
/etc/init.d/bluetooth status
● bluetooth.service - Bluetooth service
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/bluetooth.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: active (running) since Mon 2019-12-30 16:58:33 PST; 1h 8min ago
     Docs: man:bluetoothd(8)
 Main PID: 8811 (bluetoothd)
   Status: "Running"
    Tasks: 1 (limit: 4915)
   Memory: 1.1M
   CGroup: /system.slice/bluetooth.service
           └─8811 /usr/lib/bluetooth/bluetoothd

Dec 30 16:58:33 devin-HP2-Ubuntu systemd[1]: Starting Bluetooth service...
Dec 30 16:58:33 devin-HP2-Ubuntu bluetoothd[8811]: Bluetooth daemon 5.50
Dec 30 16:58:33 devin-HP2-Ubuntu systemd[1]: Started Bluetooth service.
Dec 30 16:58:33 devin-HP2-Ubuntu bluetoothd[8811]: Starting SDP server
Dec 30 16:58:33 devin-HP2-Ubuntu bluetoothd[8811]: Bluetooth management interface 1.14 initialized
```

AND

```
lsusb
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 06cb:00bb Synaptics, Inc. 
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 04f2:b67b Chicony Electronics Co., Ltd HP Wide Vision FHD Camera
Bus 001 Device 005: ID 046d:c05a Logitech, Inc. M90/M100 Optical Mouse
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

AND

```
lspci -nn
00:00.0 Host bridge [0600]: Intel Corporation Device [8086:9b61] (rev 0c)
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller [0300]: Intel Corporation Device [8086:9b41] (rev 02)
00:04.0 Signal processing controller [1180]: Intel Corporation Xeon E3-1200 v5/E3-1500 v5/6th Gen Core Processor Thermal Subsystem [8086:1903] (rev 0c)
00:12.0 Signal processing controller [1180]: Intel Corporation Device [8086:02f9]
00:13.0 Serial controller [0700]: Intel Corporation Device [8086:02fc]
00:14.0 USB controller [0c03]: Intel Corporation Device [8086:02ed]
00:14.2 RAM memory [0500]: Intel Corporation Device [8086:02ef]
00:14.3 Network controller [0280]: Intel Corporation Device [8086:02f0]
00:15.0 Serial bus controller [0c80]: Intel Corporation Device [8086:02e8]
00:15.1 Serial bus controller [0c80]: Intel Corporation Device [8086:02e9]
00:16.0 Communication controller [0780]: Intel Corporation Device [8086:02e0]
00:17.0 RAID bus controller [0104]: Intel Corporation 82801 Mobile SATA Controller [RAID mode] [8086:282a]
00:1c.0 PCI bridge [0604]: Intel Corporation Device [8086:02ba] (rev f0)
00:1c.4 PCI bridge [0604]: Intel Corporation Device [8086:02bc] (rev f0)
00:1d.0 PCI bridge [0604]: Intel Corporation Device [8086:02b0] (rev f0)
00:1d.4 PCI bridge [0604]: Intel Corporation Device [8086:02b4] (rev f0)
00:1d.6 PCI bridge [0604]: Intel Corporation Device [8086:02b6] (rev f0)
00:1f.0 ISA bridge [0601]: Intel Corporation Device [8086:0284]
00:1f.3 Multimedia audio controller [0401]: Intel Corporation Device [8086:02c8]
00:1f.4 SMBus [0c05]: Intel Corporation Device [8086:02a3]
00:1f.5 Serial bus controller [0c80]: Intel Corporation Device [8086:02a4]
01:00.0 Unassigned class [ff00]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTS525A PCI Express Card Reader [10ec:525a] (rev 01)
02:00.0 PCI bridge [0604]: Intel Corporation JHL7540 Thunderbolt 3 Bridge [Titan Ridge 2C 2018] [8086:15e7] (rev 06)
03:00.0 PCI bridge [0604]: Intel Corporation JHL7540 Thunderbolt 3 Bridge [Titan Ridge 2C 2018] [8086:15e7] (rev 06)
03:01.0 PCI bridge [0604]: Intel Corporation JHL7540 Thunderbolt 3 Bridge [Titan Ridge 2C 2018] [8086:15e7] (rev 06)
03:02.0 PCI bridge [0604]: Intel Corporation JHL7540 Thunderbolt 3 Bridge [Titan Ridge 2C 2018] [8086:15e7] (rev 06)
04:00.0 System peripheral [0880]: Intel Corporation JHL7540 Thunderbolt 3 NHI [Titan Ridge 2C 2018] [8086:15e8] (rev 06)
3a:00.0 USB controller [0c03]: Intel Corporation JHL7540 Thunderbolt 3 USB Controller [Titan Ridge 2C 2018] [8086:15e9] (rev 06)
3b:00.0 3D controller [0302]: NVIDIA Corporation GP108M [GeForce MX250] [10de:1d13] (rev a1)
3c:00.0 Non-Volatile memory controller [0108]: Intel Corporation Device [8086:0975] (rev 03)
3d:00.0 Non-Volatile memory controller [0108]: Intel Corporation Device [8086:0975]
```

Comment: I have answered a similar question https://askubuntu.com/a/1194503/890892

Comment: Hi Tejas, thanks for responding. Yes I had seen and tried your previous thread before - it didn't work. When I type bluetoothctl all I get is 'agent registered' and then '[bluetooth]#', there are no devices.
```
bluetoothctl
Agent registered
[bluetooth]# 
```