# Unable to find again a previously removed bluetooth device

Tags: sound, bluetooth, headphones

I have clicked accidentally on "remove" for my QCY-T1 Bluetoot headphones in the bloutooth settings of ubuntu 18. Now I can't connect my headphones again. There seems to be no option for "unremoving" a device. It seems that ubuntu remembers my choice and has stored it somewhere. The headphones work otherwise well with my Android phone.

Comment: I have answered a similar question https://askubuntu.com/a/1194503/890892

Comment: My headphone is also lost forever in the bluetooth memory on Ubuntu 20 once I misclicked the 'forget this device'. Is there no way to get it back like in Windows or OSX?

Comment: I had the same issue. After several trial and error attempts: I was running `bluetoothctl` on a terminal and paired/unpaired my device to my phone. Suddenly my device was shown in `bluetoothctl` and I was able to connect to it.

Answer (score 1):

I am no tech but here is how I recovered it following recommendation by Duncan Ralph aka "psathyrella" at the bottom of [this page](https://github.com/blueman-project/blueman/issues/817).

access directory /var/lib/bluetooth ,
you need to access as root (right click and select 'open root here'). Find the device in question and delete it. If you do not recognize which one it is you can connect to it with another machine and note its MAC address.

Then in terminal type

```
service bluetooth
```

and then

```
/etc/init.d/bluetooth restart
```

the device can then be re-discovered in the bluetooth GUI