# How to get my Bluetooth back on?

Tags: bluetooth

I have Ubuntu 18.04.3 LTS running on a LG gram computer and I decided to turn off my Bluetooth today in order to unpair something. Now I cannot turn it back on. This laptop originally came with Windows 10, so I am sure the Bluetooth card in my laptop has some weird stuff where it can only turn on using Windows 10 OS. So I have been searching for an easy solution for a couple hours or so and I could not find an easy solution. I am considering just going down to the store and buying a dongle. Anyway I can resolve this issue without doing that? Thanks.

Output for "lspci -knn | grep Net -A3; lsusb; dmesg | grep -i blue" is:

```
3b:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Intel Corporation Wireless 8265 / 8275 
[8086:24fd] (rev 78)
Subsystem: Intel Corporation Wireless 8265 / 8275 [8086:9010]
    Kernel driver in use: iwlwifi
    Kernel modules: iwlwifi
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 009: ID 10a5:0007  
Bus 001 Device 008: ID 04f2:0939 Chicony Electronics Co., Ltd 
Bus 001 Device 007: ID 0bda:562e Realtek Semiconductor Corp. 
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 22b8:2e25 Motorola PCS 
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
[  189.148139] Bluetooth: Core ver 2.22
[  189.148165] Bluetooth: HCI device and connection manager initialized
[  189.148168] Bluetooth: HCI socket layer initialized
[  189.148171] Bluetooth: L2CAP socket layer initialized
[  189.148179] Bluetooth: SCO socket layer initialized
[  189.260478] Bluetooth: BNEP (Ethernet Emulation) ver 1.3
[  189.260479] Bluetooth: BNEP filters: protocol multicast
[  189.260481] Bluetooth: BNEP socket layer initialized
[  189.266533] Bluetooth: hci0: BCM: chip id 73
[  189.267500] Bluetooth: hci0: BCM: features 0x07
[  189.283555] Bluetooth: hci0: BCM20702B
[  189.284546] Bluetooth: hci0: BCM20702B0 (002.001.014) build 0000
[  189.284743] bluetooth hci0: Direct firmware load for brcm/BCM20702B0-19ff-0239.hcd failed with error -2
[  189.284745] Bluetooth: hci0: BCM: Patch brcm/BCM20702B0-19ff-0239.hcd not found
[  189.342383] Bluetooth: RFCOMM TTY layer initialized
[  189.342387] Bluetooth: RFCOMM socket layer initialized
[  189.342397] Bluetooth: RFCOMM ver 1.11
[  569.923718] Bluetooth: hci0: BCM: chip id 73
[  569.924701] Bluetooth: hci0: BCM: features 0x07
[  569.940651] Bluetooth: hci0: BCM20702B
[  569.941564] Bluetooth: hci0: BCM20702B0 (002.001.014) build 0000
[  569.941576] bluetooth hci0: Direct firmware load for brcm/BCM20702B0-19ff-0239.hcd failed with error -2
[  569.941577] Bluetooth: hci0: BCM: Patch brcm/BCM20702B0-19ff-0239.hcd not found
```

I did get a Bluetooth dongle and it is working for me, but perhaps we can still figure this out. Thanks.

Comment: How did you turn the bluetooth off?

Comment: Settings app, went to bluetooth and switched it to off.

Comment: Go to Settings app, go to bluetooth and switch it on?

Comment: That does not work. It says no bluetooth found as if I don't have a bluetooth card in my laptop.

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add output of `lspci -knn | grep Net -A3; lsusb; dmesg | grep -i blue` terminal command.

Comment: The edit is now added

Comment: The output is wierd to me. 1. You have an Intel 8265 Wi-Fi device that should have BT inside. 2. dmesg shows that a Broadcom BT device is found and can't load firmware. 3. There is no Broadcom 19ff-0239 device in `lsusb`. Regarding Broadcom firmware see https://askubuntu.com/questions/632336/bluetooth-broadcom-43142-isnt-working/632348#632348

Comment: I am connected to the internet through USB tethering on my phone. Not sure if that is causing any strangeness in what you are seeing. I will read your link and see if that helps thanks.

Comment: BTW that thread is over 4 years old... but I see the answer was edited in 2019. Is this up to date?

Comment: It is up-to-date except the download links.

Comment: It seems like it would solve my problem, but its a little too complicated for me. My new bluetooth dongle works fine. Sorry for not following through with this though.

Comment: I have answered a similar question https://askubuntu.com/a/1194503/890892