# airpods 2 - ubuntu 19.10 - Thinkpad x1 extreme 2 - No success on pairing

Tags: bluetooth, thinkpad

Can't get my airpods 2 to pair successfully with my laptop. In the bluetooth menu, I see my airpods 2 but double clicking does not pair and it stays with a text of 'Not Set Up.'

I also tried with blueman to pair but blueman always says pairing failed. Did try the trick of changing `ControllerMode` in bluetooth/main.conf with either dual or bredr and both failed as well.

From `journalctl -f`, I did find this log:

```
Jan 06 07:19:36 edgar-ThinkPad-X1-Extreme-2nd gnome-control-c[5489]: Setting up /org/bluez/hci0/dev_E4_76_84_72_CB_79 failed: Timeout was reached
```

But I don't know why the pairing would timeout.

Not sure what else to try/do.

relevant specs:

```
uname -a
Linux edgar-ThinkPad-X1-Extreme-2nd 5.3.0-26-generic #28-Ubuntu SMP Wed Dec 18 05:37:46 UTC 2019 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
(Mon Jan-1 7:10:21am)-(CPU 2.9%:0:Net 60)-(edgar:~)-(1.8G:60)
> cat /etc/os-release 
NAME="Ubuntu"
VERSION="19.10 (Eoan Ermine)"
ID=ubuntu
ID_LIKE=debian
PRETTY_NAME="Ubuntu 19.10"
VERSION_ID="19.10"
HOME_URL="https://www.ubuntu.com/"
SUPPORT_URL="https://help.ubuntu.com/"
BUG_REPORT_URL="https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/"
PRIVACY_POLICY_URL="https://www.ubuntu.com/legal/terms-and-policies/privacy-policy"
VERSION_CODENAME=eoan
UBUNTU_CODENAME=eoan
> hciconfig -a
hci0:   Type: Primary  Bus: USB
    BD Address: 94:E6:F7:71:FA:47  ACL MTU: 1021:4  SCO MTU: 96:6
    UP RUNNING 
    RX bytes:4354 acl:0 sco:0 events:132 errors:0
    TX bytes:1357 acl:0 sco:0 commands:56 errors:0
    Features: 0xbf 0xfe 0x0f 0xfe 0xdb 0xff 0x7b 0x87
    Packet type: DM1 DM3 DM5 DH1 DH3 DH5 HV1 HV2 HV3 
    Link policy: RSWITCH SNIFF 
    Link mode: SLAVE ACCEPT 
    Name: 'edgar-ThinkPad-X1-Extreme-2nd'
    Class: 0x000000
    Service Classes: Unspecified
    Device Class: Miscellaneous, 
    HCI Version: 5.0 (0x9)  Revision: 0x100
    LMP Version: 5.0 (0x9)  Subversion: 0x100
    Manufacturer: Intel Corp. (2)

hcitool dev
Devices:
    hci0    94:E6:F7:71:FA:47
```

Comment: You might try using blueman (`sudo apt install blueman`). I find it a bit more reliable than the built-in tools, though it's far less pretty.

Comment: You may need to clean up the old config files in /var/lib/bluetooth/[yourbtadaptermac]/[yourbtheadphonemac] after changing ControllerMode to bredr

Comment: @KenKinder does not work with blueman, InProgress error

Comment: tried blueman (as mentioned in OP), no success with that

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Thanks to @rahduro: [Airpods 2019 bluettooth pairing problem](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1188144/airpods-2019-bluettooth-pairing-problem/1205131#1205131)

> Try adding `ControllerMode = bredr` to `/etc/bluetooth/main.conf` file.
>   Restart bluetooth service using the following command
>   `sudo systemctl restart bluetooth`.
>   Then try repairing with airpods, this worked for me
>   in 19.10.

However it would be interesting to know why it does not work for dual when it is supposed to try both modes ?

Comment: tried again on ` uname -a
Linux edgar-ThinkPad-X1-Extreme-2nd 5.3.0-42-generic #34-Ubuntu SMP Fri Feb 28 05:49:40 UTC 2020 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux` (updated since making thread) and tried this trick again, before it didn't work but now works.

Comment: but the sound is low because it can't switch to headset, just stays as headphone mode. I get `Failed to change profile to headset_head_unit` when I try to change it to headset.

Comment: @EdgarAroutiounian is it solved ?

Comment: yes, sufficiently solved. I still can't change to `headset_head_unit` but I'm not 100% if that would yield better sound quality anyway.

Comment: This also worked for airpods pro.

Comment: This worked for dell G5 dual boot

Comment: Confirmed this worked for me for airpod pro's. I had to go to `sudo bluetoothctl` and then trust the device and then connect and then it worked fine.

Comment: worked like a charm on 20.04