# How to pair+setup+connect airpod pro on ubuntu 20.04

Tags: bluetooth

I am using Ubuntu 20.04 and i own a pair of Airpod pro's.

Ubuntu detects the device but fails to pair/setup/connect. I know this because when i click it, it has a spinning logo like its attempting to connect and then it just returns back to the default "Not Set Up".

[image]

I have followed advice from [here](https://techwiser.com/fix-airpods-not-working-on-ubuntu/) setting the ControllerMode, i have tried both "dual" and "le" without any success.

```
kay@khan:~$ sudo /etc/init.d/bluetooth status

● bluetooth.service - Bluetooth service
     Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/bluetooth.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
     Active: active (running) since Sun 2020-05-17 18:13:04 BST; 2s ago
       Docs: man:bluetoothd(8)
   Main PID: 2808 (bluetoothd)
     Status: "Running"
      Tasks: 1 (limit: 18696)
     Memory: 956.0K
     CGroup: /system.slice/bluetooth.service
             └─2808 /usr/lib/bluetooth/bluetoothd

May 17 18:13:04 khan systemd[1]: Starting Bluetooth service...
May 17 18:13:04 khan bluetoothd[2808]: Bluetooth daemon 5.53
May 17 18:13:04 khan systemd[1]: Started Bluetooth service.
May 17 18:13:04 khan bluetoothd[2808]: Bluetooth management interface 1.14 initialized
May 17 18:13:04 khan bluetoothd[2808]: Endpoint registered: sender=:1.140 path=/MediaEndpoint/A2DPSink/sbc
May 17 18:13:04 khan bluetoothd[2808]: Endpoint registered: sender=:1.140 path=/MediaEndpoint/A2DPSource/sbc
```

Bluetooth device: https://www.amazon.co.uk/gp/product/B07FBSV1XZ/

Comment: A side question is there a way to clear the list of already recognized/seen devices?

Comment: Hi @Kay, if my answer worked for your main question, could you accept it?

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Short answer is: use `ControllerMode = bredr` as discussed [here](https://askubuntu.com/a/1063582/681668)

For others:

1. Set `ControllerMode = bredr` by editing `/etc/bluetooth/main.conf` file using `sudo nano /etc/bluetooth/main.conf` command (or another text editor of your choice)
2. `sudo /etc/init.d/bluetooth restart`
3. Try to pair again.

Comment: I have the same problem as the OP. This solution didn't help me. Setting mode to `bredr` and restarting service simply resulted in the headphones not responding to my clicks at all (click in default (dual) mode: spinning wheel that eventually times out, click in bredr mode: no response at all, not even spinning wheel).

Comment: this solution resolved the problem for me. had to try twice but otherwise worked fine

Comment: had same problem as @AlexanderTsepkov but connected successfully with bredr after turning off and on the bluetooth switch in the GUI

Comment: Woah, in my case there was a `#` in front of `ControllerMode` so the variable wasn't even active in the first place! You need to uncomment that line so init won't initialize with default value!

Comment: @Stiin ye if i remember correctly it did work at the time, so ill mark this as an answer, but now i just use the default settings and it works

Comment: Step 4 (already paired on wrong controller mode), If you already have paired unsuccessfully you might have to delete the previous pairing.  Run `bluetoothctl devices` on command line.    based on the output run bluetoothctl remove <the airpods pro device id>.  Restart bluetooth once again `/etc/init.d/bluetooth restart` https://askubuntu.com/questions/1285765/how-to-delete-not-set-up-bluetooth-history

Comment: Remember to uncomment the ControllerMode line.

Answer (score 4):

Steps to resolve the issue:

1. `sudo nano /etc/bluetooth/main.conf`
2. Set `ControllerMode = dual`

I had to set `dual` because my Bluetooth mouse was not being detected if I assign `bredr`.

With `dual` I can use both my wireless Bluetooth earphones as well as Bluetooth mouse simultaneously.

Answer (score 0):

In my case changeing ControllerMode to "bredr" or keeping the default value on "dual" didn't work and AirPods still trying endlessly set up connection.

When i changed ControllerMode=le and restart bluetooth it will connect to pods immidietly.

All the best!