# How to delete "Not Set Up" bluetooth history

Tags: bluetooth, uninstall, bluetooth-speaker, history-of-ubuntu

I would like to know how to delete the " Not set up" bluetooth history. I would like to clean all the unused bluetooth connections. But can't find a way to delete them. All the "Not set up" list, should be removed. However, I have no access to any of this stuffs and I just don't know how to remove them.

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Open a terminal and go into "bluetooth-mode" by typing `bluetoothctl`

Notice that a new prompt appears saying `[bluetooth]#`. You can get a list of available commands by typing `help`.

The command `devices` should list known devices with their MAC addresses. Hopefully you will be able to work out which of them you want to clear from the dialog. Note the MAC addresses of the devices you want to remove, then remove them using the `remove` command

For example, to remove the device with the MAC address `44:80:EB:98:14:28`, you would type

```
remove 44:80:EB:98:14:28
```

Comment: Thank you! It worked for me