# Unable to pair AirPods Pro with Ubuntu 22.04

Tags: bluetooth, 22.04

I tried to pair my new AirPods with a new Ubuntu 22.04 without luck.
I keep seeing "Not Set Up".

**The AirPods are able to pair with other devices.*
Tried editing the file /etc/bluetooth/main.conf and adding:  ControllerMode = bredr   OR = dual
None worked   (Did sudo /etc/init.d/bluetooth restart)

Any idea how to resolve it?
thanks!

Comment: It works for me with `ControllerMode = bredr`. I used `sudo service bluetooth restart` instead of `sudo /etc/init.d/bluetooth restart`, but I doubt that's what makes a difference. In any case you can just reboot to be sure.

Answer (score 9):

Changing ControllerMode to bredr works on my dell precision 5540.
Here is what I did (mainly repeating @korg91 and @prajeeth's steps)

1. Add `ControllerMode = bredr` to `/etc/bluetooth/main.conf` by using `sudo gedit /etc/bluetooth/main.conf`
2. Run `sudo service bluetooth restart`
3. Turn Bluetooth off and back on on the Bluetooth page in settings
4. Connect to Airpod (works)

Comment: But this will cause other bluetooth devices to be disabled, like mouse and keyboard.

Answer (score 5):

I had the same situation as yours, but changing ControllerMode to bredr, restarting the computer, and then restarting the Bluetooth service worked for me.

Comment: This worked for me, but I also had to go into bluetoothctl and delete the already existing entry for my Airpods. See https://askubuntu.com/questions/1285765/how-to-delete-not-set-up-bluetooth-history

Answer (score 5):

I encountered a similar problem on Ubuntu 20.04 and also found that using `ControllerMode` didn't resolve the issue for me. Instead, I successfully paired my AirPods using the `bluetoothctl` command-line tool, which provides an interactive interface for managing Bluetooth devices.

To pair your AirPods, you first need to find their Bluetooth address. You can do this by activating the scanning mode in `bluetoothctl` to list all nearby Bluetooth devices. Open your terminal and enter:

```bash
bluetoothctl scan on
```

This command will display a list of devices, updating in real-time. Initially, you might only see devices listed by their addresses without names, making it challenging to identify your AirPods.

[image: list of devices]

If your AirPods' name doesn't appear immediately, try putting them into pairing mode for about 10 seconds. If that doesn't work, turning off your Bluetooth and then turning it back on might force the device to show up with its name.

[image: list of deleted devices]

Once you've identified your AirPods by their address, you can pair them by executing the following command with the appropriate address:

```bash
bluetoothctl pair E0:EB:40:1D:AD:9D
```

Upon successful pairing, you'll see a confirmation message.

[image: successful pairing]

After pairing your AirPods this way, you should be able to connect to them directly from Ubuntu's Bluetooth settings without needing to use the terminal for future connections.

Answer (score 0):

Another thing to take into consideration if the connection is successful but unstable and disconnects often be sure to try another usb port. I had mine put in a random usb port or a usb hub and had many issues. One I moved it to another one the connection happens much faster and is much more stable.

Also forgetting the airpods and then using bluetoothctl to do "trust addr}" and then "pair {addr}" might also help.