# Cannot Connect AirPods to Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: 20.04, bluetooth

I am trying to connect AirPods to Ubuntu 20.04 (Kernel : 5.11.0-36-generic), I read many blog posts, but *nothing worked*, whenever I try to connect, It tries to connect for sometime, and then the Settings App just **freezes**. Can anyone please help me?
Pardon my bad English.
Thank you.

Some blogs I read and followed (which didn't work) :

[Setting up Airpods Pro on Ubuntu 20.04](https://reckoning.dev/blog/airpods-pro-ubuntu/#:%7E:text=To%20enable%20pairing%20of%20airpods,using%20sudo%20%2Fetc%2Finit.)

[How to pair+setup+connect airpod pro on ubuntu 20.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1240679/how-to-pairsetupconnect-airpod-pro-on-ubuntu-20-04)

Update: Issue resolved, see comment.

Comment: For anybody who is watching this having a similar problem, Here is a link to a post which solved the problem : https://askubuntu.com/a/1267032/1444293

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Ubuntu 20.04 bluetooth not working](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1231074/ubuntu-20-04-bluetooth-not-working)

Comment: Yes, the link I posted in the above comment worked for me. https://askubuntu.com/a/1267032/1444293

Answer (score 19):

None of these and other solutions until I tried enabling **SSPMode** with

```
btmgmt ssp on
```

if this doesn't work try disabling it with

```
btmgmt ssp off
```

Note: you need sudo rights and you might need to turn off Bluetooth to switch settings.

Comment: This worked for me perfectly on ubuntu 21.04.

Comment: this worked for me on Pop_OS 21.04. Thank you.

Comment: Helped on Ubuntu 20.04. Thanks!

Comment: had the same problem, this was the only solution that worked for me!

Answer (score 10):

For people trying to pair their AirPods max to ubuntu.

First, stop the Bluetooth service with:

```
sudo /etc/init.d/bluetooth stop
```

1. Open the Bluetooth configuration file in a text editor, using the following command.

```
sudo vi /etc/bluetooth/main.conf
```

2. add both bredr and dual mode to the Controller mode as follow:

```
ControllerMode = bredr
ControllerMode = dual
```

Then restart bluetooth

```
sudo /etc/init.d/bluetooth restart
```

You can now try to pair your device:

`press and hold the noise control button for about five seconds, or until the status light flashes white`

Comment: thanks man, switching it to bredr instead of dual made it work for me. could even revert the changes after pairing and it kept recognizing & connecting.

Answer (score 0):

None of these solutions worked for me.

I followed [this](https://gist.github.com/aidos-dev/b49078c1d8c6bb1621e4ac199d18213b) blog (ack aitos-dev), which works like a charm.

Basically, is modifying the ControllerMode under the Bluetooth configuration, so that it works in bedr mode. Then I restarted the Bluetooth service, and the AirPods were able to connect.

```
sudo vi /etc/bluetooth/main.conf
```

Find the next line:

```
#ControllerMode = dual
```

Change "dual" to "bredr". The final line must be:

```
ControllerMode = bredr
```

Restart the bluetooth service:

```
sudo /etc/init.d/bluetooth restart
```

Just to give more context, a quick differentiation between the allowed ControllerModes (dual, bredr, le):

- ControllerMode = dual: Bluetooth controller supports both older and
  newer Bluetooth devices, offering compatibility and better
  performance, but it may consume more power.
- ControllerMode = bredr: Bluetooth controller supports only older
  Bluetooth devices, ensuring compatibility with them and potentially
  saving power. It does not support newer Bluetooth devices with
  enhanced performance.
- ControllerMode = le: Bluetooth controller operates exclusively in
  Bluetooth Low Energy (BLE) mode, supporting only BLE devices. This
  mode is suitable for applications that require low power consumption
  and are focused on BLE device interactions. It does not support older
  BR/EDR Bluetooth devices.

After the AirPods got connected, I could even revert the config to the original one, restart the Bluetooth service, and still be able to reconnect.