# Bluetooth doesn't list my Razer Basilisk mouse for pairing

Tags: bluetooth, mouse

I have connected my keyboard via Bluetooth on Ubuntu.

Made sure my mouse(**Razer Basilisk**) is also on pairing mode(blue light blinks twice repeatedly after pressing *side buttons+dpi button* for 3 seconds). I can confirm this as my phone can detect the mouse for pairing.

But Ubuntu doesn't detect my mouse. Please help.

Comment: Do you have openrazer installed?

Comment: @Steve I just did and it still doesn't detect my mouse.

Comment: I am unable to connect my DeathAdder via Bluetooth on Fedora either. We might be stuck using the 2.4ghz receiver.

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem with a Cobra Pro - other bluetooth devices were visible but not the mouse. The problem was my bluetooth controller mode was set to bredr but I think the mouse uses le.

I followed https://askubuntu.com/a/1123633/1091963 to set the controller to dual and then I could connect the mouse via bluetooth:

```
sudo nano /etc/bluetooth/main.conf
```

Then make sure controller mode is set to dual or commented out to default (dual)

`ControllerMode = dual` or `# ControllerMode = bredr`

Bluetooth manager in the link also seems to work better than Ubuntu's built in bluetooth manager.

[image: Bluetooth manager with different mode devices paired]