# BT headset creates echo or microphone does not work

Tags: sound, bluetooth, pulseaudio, microphone

Lately I made another attempt of completely switching from Windows to Ubuntu (20.10).
From earlier tries I know that compatibility stuff is sometimes rough with Linux.
However, I really got stuck trying to get my BT-Headset (Beyerdynamic Lagoon ANC) to work.
When I select "High sound quality A2DP" the sound is fine, but it automatically switches to the build in Mic instead of the Headset. And when I reselect the Headset Input or switch the Profile, I get a real bad echo of my own voice.
I found this seven year old answer ([Headphones microphone is not working](https://askubuntu.com/questions/354383/headphones-microphone-is-not-working)), saying it is in general impossible to get A2DP in parallel with input. But as the headset worked fine without echo under Windows, there's technically gotta be some way to at least get rid of the echo.
I already updated all the Bluetooth stuff and installed pulse audio. No results.
Does anyone have an idea?
Thanks in regard

Comment: Similar problem here with the Sony WH-1000xm3